# VARCHAR length error when using StringEncryptedType, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following model:

```
from enum import Enum
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import StringEncryptedType
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Float,
    Enum as SQAEnum,
    String
)
from backend.db import Base
from backend.config import Config


class AuthProviders(Enum):
    google = "Google"
    facebook = "Facebook"
    vest = "Vest"


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(StringEncryptedType(String(255), Config.MYSQL_ENCRYPT_KEY))
    auth_provider = Column(SQAEnum(AuthProviders))
    timestamp = Column(Float(precision=32))
```

which alembic uses to generate the following migration script:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import StringEncryptedType

from backend.config import Config

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'b919cf558155'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('users',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=255), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('hashed_password', StringEncryptedType(sa.String(255), Config.MYSQL_ENCRYPT_KEY), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('auth_provider', sa.Enum('google', 'facebook', 'vest', name='authproviders'), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('timestamp', sa.Float(precision=32), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_users_email'), 'users', ['email'], unique=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_index(op.f('ix_users_email'), table_name='users')
    op.drop_table('users')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I added the line `from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import StringEncryptedType` and edited the `hashed_password` column entry so that it matches the models file.

When I run the DB upgrade I'm thrown the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'users', column 'hashed_password'): VARCHAR requires a length on dialect mysql
```

I'm confused by this, because I've defined the length of the `String` that's being encrypted. Replacing `String` with `VARCHAR` doesn't solve the problem.

The `__init__` for for `StringEncryptedType` is pretty straight-forward:

```
def __init__(self, type_in=None, key=None, engine=None, padding=None, **kwargs):
```

Apparently `EncryptedType` for strings is deprecated in favor of `StringEncryptedType`, but having a hard time making the switch. What else needs to happen here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing the `String` column type and a separate `length` keyword argument seems to work.

This model

```py
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users20201212a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(StringEncryptedType(String, length=255, key='abc'))
    auth_provider = Column(SQAEnum(AuthProviders))
    timestamp = Column(Float(precision=32))
```

generates this DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE users20201212a (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        email VARCHAR(255), 
        hashed_password VARCHAR(255), 
        auth_provider ENUM('google','facebook','vest'), 
        timestamp FLOAT(32), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. Assuming `import sqlalchemy as sqla`, this failed: `token = sqla.Column(StringEncryptedType(sqla.String(3000), getenv('DB_ENCRYPTION_KEY'), AesGcmEngine, 'pkcs5'), nullable=True)`, whereas this worked: `token = sqla.Column(StringEncryptedType(sqla.String, getenv('DB_ENCRYPTION_KEY'), AesGcmEngine, 'pkcs5', length=3000), nullable=True)`